# How to get value of property from object of class at runtime using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, getproperty

I have a class something like below:

```
Class A : B<C>
{
    public A(C entity):base(entity)
    {}
}

abstract class B<T>
{
    public B(T entity)
        {
            Entity = entity;
        }

        public T Entity { get; private set; }
}

Class C: D
{
    public string prop2{get;set;}
}
Class D
{
    public string prop1{get;set;}
}
 Main()
 {
 A obj = new A(new C());
 obj.GetType().GetProperty("prop1",  BindingsFlag.Instance|BindingsFlag.FlatteredHierarchy)//  is null


 }
```

I have object of class A.
I want to get property value from this object at runtime.

I am trying with

```
obj.GetType().GetProprty("propertyName", 
                         BindingsFlag.FlattenHierarchy).GetValue(obj, null);
```

However GetProprty() is returing null as that property is declared either in D or C class.

Can someone please suggest me how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide us a reproducible example, and spell the method names correctly?

Comment: BTW this should have been asked many times..........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
GetType().GetProperty("propertyName", BindingsFlag.FlattenHierarchy)
         .GetValue(obj, null);
```

You are misssing binding flag that specifies wheter get instance or static property:

```
 BindingsFlag.FlattenHierarchy | BindingsFlag.Instance
```

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/zy0d4103(v=vs.110).aspx) flag `BindingsFlag.Instance` or `BindingsFlag.Static` must be specifed explicity in order to get not null values:

> You must specify either BindingFlags.Instance or BindingFlags.Static
>   in order to get a return.

What's more, `public` properties are exlcuded by default. So if you property is `public`  you need to specify additional flag:

```
BindingsFlag.FlattenHierarchy | BindingsFlag.Instance | BindingsFlag.Public
```

Remarks:

> Specify BindingFlags.Public to include public properties in the
>   search.

If property in base is private, `FlattenHierarchy` will not enumerate it:

> (...) private static members in inherited classes are not included
>   If this is your case, I am afraid that you have to manually travel through base class and search for that property.

Make also sure, that property name is valid and exists.

**EDIT:**
After your edit, I see the problem. **Your class A is not sub-class of D class (you want to get property from D class).** That is why getting property value is not working in such way.
You need to follow the following steps:

```
// get entity prop value
var entityValue =
    (obj.GetType()
        .GetProperty("Entity", 
           BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
        .GetValue(obj));
// get prop value
var prop1Value =
    entityValue.GetType()
               .GetProperty("prop1", 
                  BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | 
                  BindingFlags.Instance | 
                  BindingFlags.Public)
               .GetValue(entityValue);
```

Remember to handle **null** values etc.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I have tried with BindingFlag.Instance     however it did not work

Comment: thanks but did not work, please see I have added an example for more understanding of question

Comment: there are typos in some of the code, `BindingsFlags` is plural